# Powershell Balloon Notification Vanishes before showing

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10

Have another head scratcher here, simply put my balloon notification does not work when fired from inside of a function that is inside of a job, the icon shows up for a fraction of a second and then disappears, tried several compinations of -wait -sleep -sleep-start to see if i could delay its "completion" since i feel the function is not running it's full course before ending, it works outside of the job/function, but inside it does not, here is the snippet I am calling

```
function MakeToolTip
{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$Text,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$Title,

[ValidateSet(‘None’, ‘Info’, ‘Warning’, ‘Error’)]
$Icon = ‘Info’,    $Timeout = 10000
)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

if ($script:balloon -eq $null)
{
$script:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
}

$path                    = Get-Process -id $pid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
$balloon.Icon            = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon  = $Icon
$balloon.BalloonTipText  = $Text
$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = $Title
$balloon.Visible         = $true

$balloon.ShowBalloonTip($Timeout)
}
```

This is called with: `MakeToolTip "Testing" "VNC Connections" Info`

The full code of the script is here, lines 239-269: https://pastebin.com/7Q4gwLJe

I'm considering running the balloon in a separate job? Maybe the pipeline is completing it too quickly because there too much other stuff going on?

#### EDIT

Finding that when wrapped in a job a balloon notification does not work, very strange behavior

```
$MakeToolTip =
{

function Makeit {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$Text,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$Title,

[ValidateSet(‘None’, ‘Info’, ‘Warning’, ‘Error’)]
$Icon = ‘Info’,    $Timeout = 10000
)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

if ($balloon -eq $null)
{
$balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
}

$path                    = Get-Process -id $pid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
$balloon.Icon            = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon  = $Icon
$balloon.BalloonTipText  = $Text
$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = $Title
$balloon.Visible         = $true

$balloon.ShowBalloonTip($Timeout)
write-host $Text, $Title
}
}

$balloonjob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {MakeIt 'Hi' 'There'} -InitializationScript $MakeToolTip -Name "BalloonJob"
        Register-ObjectEvent $balloonjob -EventName StateChanged -Action {
            if ($eventArgs.JobStateInfo.State -eq [System.Management.Automation.JobState]::Failed)
            {
                Write-Host "Closing the Balloon"
                # This command removes the original job
                $sender | Remove-Job -Force
                
                # These commands remove the event registration
                $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event -Force
                $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job -Force
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have 'Alarms Only' or 'Priority Only' enabled in Focus Assist on Windows 10.  If you do, this will immediately dismiss the alert.

Comment: The setting is set to off, that would have been cool to have be the answer though, the notification does work outside of the function / job.

Comment: Might it be a scope issue?  Try declaring `$balloon` outside of your `MakeToolTip` function, then inside your `MakeToolTip` function, always reference `$Script:balloon` consistently; instead of just `$balloon` (local scope).

Comment: @leeharvey1 I tried that, declared it as null before the function, after the function, and inside the function, and added the $Script before all the balloon variables, same results though with the instant dismissal. Was thinking maybe another notification was keeping it ignored so I cleared the notification cue, no change, going to try a separate job even though I hate adding a third to the script.

Comment: Making a separate job did not do the trick either, what a head-scratcher!

Comment: Finding that encapsulated in a job a balloon function does not work, wrapped inside or outside of a function, very strange behavior